# Not able to access folder due to wrong CHMOD commands

Tags: permissions, apache2, directory

I was not able to view my custom vhost www.ajweb.dev in my apache2.

My www folder resided in /home/ajinkya/www

So I did following.

```
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~$ cd www
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ chmod 755 ./www
chmod: cannot access `./www': No such file or directory
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ chmod 755 ../www
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ sudo chmod 755 ../www
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ sudo useradd -g www-data ajinkya
useradd: user 'ajinkya' already exists
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ sudo chown -R www-data /home/ajinkya/www
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                      Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/ajinkya/www/aj/ajweb] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/ajinkya/www/aj/ajweb] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:~/www$ cd /etc/apache2/
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:/etc/apache2$ cd sites-enabled/
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls
000-default  000-default~  ajweb.dev  ajweb.dev~
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo gedit ajweb.dev
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                      apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
ajinkya@ajinkya-Inspiron-3521:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$
```

**And now Im not able to view/open that folder manually.**

[image]

```
ls -l /home/ajinkya | grep www
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data ajinkya    4096 Sep 11 15:33 www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your attempt to join the www-data group failed.
Try this command `sudo adduser ajinkya www-data`

To verify you are in the www-data group, run `groups` and it should show up in the list. You may need to log out and back in.

Then you can change the permission to 775 (safer for a www directory) with `sudo chmod -R 775 ~/www`

Comment: I did this

sudo chmod -R 775 /home/ajinkya/www

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /home/ajinkya/www